# OGNL Expression Injection: Struts 2

Tags: struts2, fortify

how can i fix this vulnerability?

Kingdom: Input Validation and Representation

Abstract: Using wildcards (*) in Struts 2 action names allows evaluation of action names as OGNL expressions effectively allowing an attacker to modify system variables like Session or execute arbitrary commands on the server.

```
<action name="MyAction_*" class="MyActionClass" method="{1}">
```

thanks

Comment: What exactly is "this vulnerability"?

Comment: A critical vulnerability on the system fortify : OGNL Expression Injection: Struts 2.

Answer (score 0):

You update your S2 version, just like a trivial web search says you should.

Alternatively, you follow the advice given in the [S2 vulnerability page](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WW/S2-015):

```
<constant name="struts.allowed.action.names" value="[a-zA-Z]*" />
```

*Noting that this vulnerability is a half-decade old now, and was fixed a long time ago.*